# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException::$validator

Tags: laravel

I am trying to save my form data in my DB but I keep getting this error. Don't know where the problem is, I tried finding several solutions, none worked. I tried this in another module, it works there but it doesn't work here, could this be a Route issue or duplicate values issues? FYI Few DB tables are also being used by other similar forms in the same project.

[StackTrace Here](https://flareapp.io/share/w5BB2rD5)

My Model: (Admission.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class Admission extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'admissions';

    protected function createAdmission(array $data)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:admissions'],
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
        }

        $admission = self::create([
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'dob' => $data['dob'],
            'ad1' => $data['ad1'],
            'ad2' => $data['ad2'],
            'ad3' => $data['ad3'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'pin' => $data['pin'],
            'phnumber' => $data['phnumber'],
            'altnumber' => $data['altnumber'],
            'schoolname' => $data['schoolname'],
            'board' => $data['board'],
            'subject' => $data['subject'],
            'marks' => $data['marks'],
            'schoolname2' => $data['schoolname2'],
            'board2' => $data['board2'],
            'subject2' => $data['subject2'],
            'marks2' => $data['marks2'],
            'collname' => $data['collname'],
            'degree' => $data['degree'],
            'special' => $data['special'],
            'cgpa' => $data['cgpa'],
            'father' => $data['father'],
            'mother' => $data['mother'],
            'category' => $data['category'],
            'blood' => $data['blood'],
            'regstatus' => $data['regstatus'],
            'nationality' => $data['nationality'],
            'adhaar' => $data['adhaar'],
            'ad4' => $data['ad4'],
            'ad5' => $data['ad5'],
            'ad7' => $data['ad7'],
            'country2' => $data['country2'],
            'state2' => $data['state2'],
            'city2' => $data['city2'],
            'pin2' => $data['pin2'],
            'quota' => $data['quota'],
            'courselist' => $data['courselist'],
            'coursepricelist' => $data['coursepricelist'],
            'guardnum' => $data['guardnum'],
            'parentnum' => $data['parentnum'],
            'email2' => $data['email2'],
            'test' => $data['test'],
            'year' => $data['year'],
            'score' => $data['score'],
            'rank' => $data['rank'],
        ]);

        if (request()->hasFile('photo')) {
            $photo = request()->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
            request()->file('photo')->storeAs('photos', $admission->id . '/' . $photo, '');
            $admission->update(['photo' => $photo]);
        }

        if (request()->hasFile('signature')) {
            $signature = request()->file('signature')->getClientOriginalName();
            request()->file('signature')->storeAs('signatures', $admission->id . '/' . $signature, '');
            $admission->update(['signature' => $signature]);
        }
        
        if (request()->hasAny('country')) {
            $country_data = DB::table('countries')->where('id', request()->country)->pluck('name')->first();
            $admission->update(['country' => $country_data]);
        }

        if (request()->hasAny('state')) {
            $state_data = DB::table('states')->where('id', request()->state)->pluck('name')->first();
            $admission->update(['state' => $state_data]);
        }

        if (request()->hasAny('city')) {
            $city_data = DB::table('cities')->where('id', request()->city)->pluck('name')->first();
            $admission->update(['city' => $city_data]);
        }

        if (request()->hasAny('school')) {
            $school_data = DB::table('schools')->where('id', request()->school)->pluck('name')->first();
            $admission->update(['school' => $school_data]);
        }

        if (request()->hasAny('course')) {
            $course_data = DB::table('courses')->where('id', request()->course)->pluck('name')->first();
            $admission->update(['course' => $course_data]);
        }

        if (request()->hasAny('quota')) {
            $quota_data = DB::table('quotas')->where('id', request()->course)->pluck('name')->first();
            $admission->update(['quota' => $quota_data]);
        }

        if (request()->hasAny('courselist')) {
            $courselist_data = DB::table('courselist')->where('id', request()->course)->pluck('name')->first();
            $admission->update(['courselist' => $courselist_data]);
        }

        if (request()->hasAny('coursepricelist')) {
            $coursepricelist_data = DB::table('coursepricelist')->where('id', request()->course)->pluck('price')->first();
            $admission->update(['coursepricelist' => $coursepricelist_data]);
        }

        return $admission;
    }
}
```

My Controller: (AdmissionDropdownController.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Admission;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Exception;

class AdmissionDropdownController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->all();
            // dd($data);

            try {
                $admission = Admission::createAdmission($data);

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return back()->withErrors($e->validator)
                    ->withInput();
            }
            $queryString = urlencode(base64_encode(http_build_query(["id" => $admission->id, 
            "phnumber" => $admission->phnumber, "email" => $admission->email, 
            "coursepricelist" => $admission->coursepricelist])));
            return redirect()->route('admission-payment.initiate', ["data" => $queryString]);
        }

        $quotas = DB::table("quotas")->pluck("name", "id");
        $countries = DB::table("countries")->pluck("name", "id");
        return view('admission-form', compact('countries', 'quotas'));
    }

    public function getStatesList(Request $request)
    {
        $states = DB::table("states")
            ->where("country_id", $request->country_id)
            ->pluck("name", "id");
        return response()->json($states);
    }

    public function getCitiesList(Request $request)
    {
        $cities = DB::table("cities")
            ->where("state_id", $request->state_id)
            ->pluck("name", "id");
        return response()->json($cities);
    }

    public function getCoursesList(Request $request)
    {
        $courselist = DB::table("courselist")
            ->where("quota_id", $request->quota_id)
            ->pluck("name", "id");
        return response()->json($courselist);
    }

    public function getCoursePriceList(Request $request)
    {
        $coursepricelist = DB::table("coursepricelist")
            ->where("course_id", $request->course_id)
            ->pluck("price", "id");
        return response()->json($coursepricelist);
    }
}
```

My Routes: (web.php)

```
Route::get('admission-form', 'AdmissionDropdownController@index')->name('admission-form');
Route::post('admission-form', 'AdmissionDropdownController@index');

Route::get('get-states-list', 'AdmissionDropdownController@getStatesList');
Route::get('get-cities-list', 'AdmissionDropdownController@getCitiesList');
Route::get('get-courses-list', 'AdmissionDropdownController@getCoursesList');
Route::get('get-courseprice-list', 'AdmissionDropdownController@getCoursePriceList');
```

Comment: can you see what $e is print_r or var dump

Comment: its not the validation that is failing (it is not the ValidationException that you are catching), you are getting a mass assignment exception from the `self::create(...)` call or any of the `$admission->update(...)` calls

Comment: Ok I resolved mass assignment issue but now I am getting this error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\QueryException::$validator`-- check the stack trace [here](https://flareapp.io/share/lm2OkGnP)